# Java: Reference to sub array of bytes

Tags: java, unit-testing, byte, arrays

Unit Tests: Setup a byte array with **poison barriers**. If in the frame of the test any boarder is touched, the unit test shall fail, such as in the following fragment:

```
byte[]    memory = new byte[Size + 2];

/* Poison barriers. Failure in case of touch! */
memory[0]      = 0x5A; 
memory[Size-1] = 0xA5; 

...
    array = sub-array of memory[] from '1 to Size-2'
    test functions on array
...
/* Check if boarders have been touched. */
hwut_verify(memory[0]      == 0x5A);
hwut_verify(memory[Size-1] == 0xA5);
```

How could I get the sub-array that is actually located inside the original byte array?

Comment: You can copy it by using `System.arraycopy` but you can't get a reference  (or a pointer if you like) to subarray. For that you could use `ByteBuffer` instead of `byte[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, a byte[] has a header which includes it's maximum length.  This means you can't get a sub byte[] as it wouldn't be an Object.

What you can do is use ByteBuffer

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
ByteBuffer portion = bb.position(10).limit(20).slice();
```

Comment: Does any action on 'portion' effect 'byteArray'?

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer you can change the position and limit of `portion` independently but if you write bytes to one in that area it is visible to both. i.e. they are actually working on the say array.  Note: ByteBuffer support off heap memory as well.